# Characterizing $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ via a property of its tensor powers

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials, tensor-powers

Let $\varphi: \mathbb{Q}[X] \longrightarrow R$ an inclusion of commutative rings.  Suppose that the map
$$- \circ \varphi: \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Q}\operatorname{-alg}}(R, R^{\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} n}) \longrightarrow \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Q}\operatorname{-alg}}(\mathbb{Q}[X], R^{\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} n}) \cong R^{\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} n}$$ is a bijection for all nonnegative integers $n$ (where $R^{\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} 0} = \mathbb{Q}$). Must the map $\varphi$ be an isomorphism? If so, then, replacing $\mathbb{Q}$ with an arbitrary field $k$ of characteristic zero, is the corresponding statement true?

The question is motivated by questions about plethories, specifically, [Classification of plethories over $\mathbb{Q}$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/113989/classification-of-plethories-over-mathbbq)

In the original version of the question I did not include the assumption that $\operatorname{char} k = 0$. If you leave out that assumption then $\varphi$ need not be an isomorphism.  A nice counterexample is provided below by Julian Rosen.

Comment: The symbol $\cong$ in the second line seems to be wrong.

Comment: I assume OP means for these to be homs for the category of $k$-algebras, where the $\cong$ is correct.

Comment: Sorry.  I meant $k$-algebra homs.  I edited it.

Comment: Is $R$ commutative?

Comment: Yes. I meant to say $R$ commutative (and associative).

Comment: Is $R$ augmented?

Comment: I included $n = 0$ so Hom from $R$ to $k$ is in bijection with $k$.

Comment: So you mean that $R$ is augmented over $k$, but not necessarily over $k[X]$?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question means.  You could say that $R$ is augmented with a family of $k$-algebra homomorphisms to $k$, parameterized by $k$; no one of them is special.  The map from the first hom set to the second simply pre-composes with the homomorphism $k[X] \longrightarrow R$.

Comment: I mean that you don't suppose that there is a section $R\rightarrow k[X]$.

Comment: Oh ok, I don't assume that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question...I just proved (finally) that it's true assuming a positive answer to the question [Classification of plethories over $\mathbb{Q}$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/113989/classification-of-plethories-over-mathbbq), that is, assuming that every $\mathbb{Q}$-plethory is linear.  Basically, the proof goes by showing that the given condition implies that $R$ has a $\mathbb{Q}$-plethory structure such that the comonad structure $W_R \longrightarrow W_R W_R$ is an isomorphism, and then its purported linearity implies that $R$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-plethory.

Answer (score 12):

Let $p$ be a prime. Take $k=\mathbb{F}_p$,
$$
R=k[X,X^{1/p},X^{1/p^2},\ldots].
$$
For any $k$-algebra $A$, there is a natural bijection
$$
\mathrm{Hom}_{k\text{-alg}}(R,A)\cong\big\{(a_0,a_1,\ldots):a_n\in A, a_0=a_1^p, a_1=a_2^p,\ldots\big\},
$$
where $\varphi:R\to A$ corresponds to $(\varphi(X),\varphi(X^{1/p}),\ldots)$. If every element of $A$ has a unique $p$-th root, then the natural map
$$
\mathrm{Hom}_{k\text{-alg}}(R,A)\to \mathrm{Hom}_{k\text{-alg}}(k[X],A)
$$
is a bijection. Every element of $R^{\otimes_k n}$ has a unique $p$-th root, so this gives a counterexample to the first question.

Comment: Nice!  How about if $k$ is assumed to have characteristic zero?