# On the analogy between $p$-derivations and derivations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra

$\DeclareMathOperator\Spec{Spec}$Let $p$ be a prime number, and $A$ a commutative ring. Recall that a [$p$-derivation on $A$](https://kskedlaya.org/prismatic/sec_delta-rings.html), or a *$\delta$-ring* structure on $A$ is a set map $\delta : A \to A$ such that $\phi(x) = x^p + p\delta(x)$ is a ring homomorphism; if $p$ is a zero-divisor in $A$, it is additionally required that "$\delta$ satisfies all equations which this description would entail had $A$ been $p$-torsionfree" (see the link for a precise definition). Thus $\delta$ encodes a sort of "rigid lift of Frobenius" from $A/p$.

There is an analogy lurking in the term "$p$-derivation": the analogy says that $\delta$ is something like a derivation. I would like to understand this analogy better.

**Question 1:** In what ways is it useful to think of a $p$-derivation as being like a derivation?

**Question 2:** Are there places where the analogy comes up short, and we should not really think that a $p$-derivation is like a derivation?

**Notes:**

- There are at [least](https://bookstore.ams.org/surv-118/) two [books](https://bookstore.ams.org/surv-222), both by Buium, which take this analogy and run with it. So I should probably start by reading the introductions to these books in detail.
- There's also a [theorem](https://doi.org/10.1006/jabr.1997.7177), again of Buium which says that in some weak "up to isogeny" sense the derivations, $p$-derviations, difference operators, and $p$-difference operators are the "only" [plethories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/plethory) satisfying some conditions. But the result is not quite as crisp as one might like. See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/114048/2362) for some discussion.
- Note that all the references so far are due to a single author (Buium). I'd appreciate getting a perspective which puts Buium's work into context with number theory and algebraic geometry in general.
- (**Question 3:**) One thing I'd like to understand in these terms is the universal property of the $p$-typical Witt vectors. I guess $\Spec W(A)$ is $\Spec A$ with a "$p$-tangent-direction freely added to it" or something? What is the analogous object when $p$-derivations are replaced with ordinary derivations?

Comment: For question 3, and a ring $A$, I guess the analog to $W(A)$ is $A[[t]]$.

Comment: just refining the answer for 3, I think it is not A[[t]] but a divided power version of same, I learned this from a talk of Jim Borger but the construction is as follows. if (R, d) is a differential ring and f: R -> A is a ring homomorphism, you can observe that the formula r \mapsto sum f(d^n(r)) t^n / n! defines a homomorphism, and this is the same story as for Witt vectors, easier because everything is additive.

Comment: sorry let me say that better: the forgetful functor from differential rings to ordinary rings has a right adjoint, sometimes called W^diff, which is given in formulas by divided power series as I wrote above.

Comment: Regarding your Q3 (understood as "what is really Witt vectors functor"), you can read any papers of Hesselholt and Kaledin on (topological) Hochschild-Witt complex, esp. "Witt vectors as a polynomial functor". I guess you can try to reformulate state of the art into (p-)derivations language, by noting that all reasonable ring operations arise as sections of a projection $\pi: T(A) \to A$, where T is a polynomial (...usually quadratic) functor on category of (noncommutative) rings, and $\pi$ is a natural transformation.